# Is there a way to integrate solace with spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, solace, solace-mq

I'm looking to integrate solace with spring batch process/vise-versa where the spring itemwriter should be a solace topic/queue. Is there a way to do this? I have a few tips on spring with solace but those are independent messages. I' looking for batch insertion to solace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solace has a Spring Framework integration guide over at http://dev.solacesystems.com/integration-guides/spring-framework/

It has the necessary `JmsTemplate` configuration that is required by Spring Batch's `JmsItemWriter` or `JmsItemReader`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Solace does support JMS, Spring Batch does have a `JmsItemWriter` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/jms/JmsItemWriter.html).  Beyond that, if you were looking to use something Solace specific, you'd need to write your own `ItemWriter` implementation.

Comment: I'm looking at JmsItemWriter from spring, but just wondering what else I need to do apart from this. I have a reader, processor, writer and jmstemplate fort he writer configured. Is that it, or should I do something in the code by extending the writer? I just want what was processed to be written directly